# Modifying variable in a for loop batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, path

Hi I'm trying to make a batch file that digs thru a directory and checks if all the files in its sub-directories are the same as in another directory (with the same name and same sub-directory names)

ex:

```
C:/Users/Administrator/desktop/directory1/global/config/project.config

C:/directory2/global/config/project.config
```

I'm able to fetch all the files that need to be compared with a for loop
The echo %%f gives me a path like:

```
C:/Users/Administrator/directory1/global/config/project.config
```

But I want to remove the beginning and store it in a new variable so I can easily compare files with an FC command. I don't know how to correctly do a string substitution when in a for loop. I want to get just this:

```
/global/config/project.config
```

my code for now

```
set b="c:\Users\Administrator\desktop\"
set j=""
for /f %%f in ('dir /a:-d /s /b /r c:\Users\Administrator\desktop\global') do (
set c=%%f
%c:b=j%
echo %%c
)
```

Comment: Strong suggestion: *DON'T* do this with a .bat file.  Use a VBScript, or Powershell. Or Python or Perl. Or C# or VB.Net. *Anything* but DOS .bat files.  You'll be much happier - and much more productive - in the long run.  IMHO...

Comment: PS: If you really must, this might help: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: I agree... But I'm expanding an already existing batch file... I don't want to start launching other stuff thru this .bat
I could create a .vbs in temp and insert the code lines thru the bat file but I want to stay kosher and stick with dos commands.

Comment: you need `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`  -> http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: how do you get only the path without the filename after?
I tried doing this but doesnt work

  set "j=!file_path:%dir1%=%dir2%!"
then
  echo !~pj!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "dir1=c:\smth"
set "dir2=c:\dir\smth2"

setlocal enableDelyaedExpansion
for /f %%F in ('dir  /a:-d /s /b /r "%dir1%"') do (
  set "file_path=%%F"
  if not exist "!file_path:%dir1%=%dir2%!" (
     echo file %%F does not exists in %dir2% 
  )
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to use a call function

```
setlocal enableDelyaedExpansion
for /f %%F in ('dir  /a:-d /s /b /r "%dir1%"') do call :foo %%F

:foo 
set "file_path=%1"
if not exist "!file_path:%dir1%=%dir2%!" (
echo file %1 does not exists in %dir2% 
)
```